# Group and merge similar javascript objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, lodash

I have the following data and I am stuck between a logic

```
[
    {
        "user.employeeId": "10081",
        "objectives": [
            "Improve consultation"
        ],
        "param": "dueByDays"
    },
    {
        "user.employeeId": "10081",
        "objectives": [
            "Building a strong team"
        ],
        "param": "overdue"
    },
]
```

How can I get the data in the below format, I have tried Map(), ForEach(), etc. but I am getting stuck,
This is the requirement/Output

```
[
      {
        'user.employeeId': '10081',
        params: [
          {
            objectives: ['Improve consultation'],
            param: 'dueByDays'
          },
          {
            objectives: ['Building a strong team'],
            param: 'overdue'
          },          
          {
            objectives: null,
            param: 'dueToday'
          }

        ]
}];
```

If suppose `param` is not available, we still need to set `objective` as null, please help me out regarding this query. It would be better if anyone can help me do this using `lodash`
There will be only 3 params as mentioned above

Comment: Which one of the snippets is "before" and which is "after"? I.e., what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The first one is snippet before, and the last one is the required output

Comment: Do you need to have the same order of employee in the second array ?

Comment: Not necessary @Axnyff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
const employeesData = {};

for (let item of array) {
  const id = item["user.employeeId"];
  if (!employeesData[id]) {
    employeesData[id] = {};
  }
  employeesData[id][item.param] = item.objectives;
}

const params = ['dueByDays', 'overdue', 'dueToday'];
const result = [];
for (let key of Object.keys(employeesData)) {
  result.push({
    'user.employeeId': key,
    params: params.map(param => ({
      param,
      objectives: employeesData[key][param] || null,
    })),
  });
}
```

We first build an object containing all the data then we iterate through the keys to build a proper array.

Answer (score 2):

The approach here would be something like this:

- create some "storage" object (can be a simple object);
- iterate through items;
- if this is a new employee, then create new record in the "storage";
- if this is a known employee, just update its info.

After this, the storage object has to be converted to an array, as per requirement:

```js
const userEntries = /* initial array */;
const tempStorage = Object.create(null); // or just '{}'

for (const entry of userEntries) {
  const id = entry["user.employeeId"];
  const param = {
    objectives: entry.objectives,
    param: entry.param,
  };

  if (id in tempStorage === false) { // this is a new employee
    tempStorage[id] = [ param ];
  } else { // this is a known employee, it exists in storage
    tempStorage[id].push(param);
  }
}

// All the necessary data is in tempStorage.
// Now on to converting.

const output = [];

for (const employeeId in tempStorage) {
  output.push({
    ["user.employeeId"]: employeeId,
    params: tempStorage[employeeId],
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't need to use storage! need to use this data as it is for further operations

Comment: You might've not understand its purpose. This storage is a temporary structure to make lists' conversion possible. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: Understood! Trying this approach as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't test it but it should work.

```
const usersHash = users.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc[curr["user.employeeId"]])
    acc[curr["user.employeeId"]].params.push(curr.param ? {...curr.param} : {})
  else
    acc[curr["user.employeeId"]] = { "user.employeeId": curr["user.employeeId"], params: [{...curr.param}] }
  return acc;
},{})

const mergedUsers = Object.values(usersHash);
```

Comment: I tested this, it is working but doesn't satisfy a condition - if **param** is not present the param should be pushed ith the objective as *null*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. The following code should work.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "user.employeeId": "10081",
        "objectives": [
            "Improve consultation"
        ],
        "param": "dueByDays"
    },
    {
        "user.employeeId": "10081",
        "objectives": [
            "Building a strong team"
        ],
        "param": "overdue"
    },
    {
        "user.employeeId": "10081",
        "objectives": [
            "A team"
        ],
    },
]


const result = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)  => {
  const element = accumulator.find(item => item['user.employeeId'] === currentValue['user.employeeId'])
  if (element) {
    element.params.push({objectives: currentValue.objectives, param: currentValue.param || null})
  } else {
    accumulator.push({'user.employeeId': currentValue['user.employeeId'], params: [{objectives: currentValue.objectives, param: currentValue.param || null}]})
  }
  return accumulator
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your approach is correct! how can I add value as null for **param** which is not present

Comment: You can use the OR operator to check conditionally if param is present, if not it will assign null to param. I have updated the code above. It should now work when param is not defined.

Comment: ```const params = ['dueByDays', 'overdue', 'dueToday']```. The param should not be returned as null, **param** should be there and objective for that corresponding should be `null`